# Print outside the imageable area

Tags: java, printing, area

I am trying to print some letters at the very top of the page (or atleast as much on the top/left or top/right as I can), I've tried to force it to be able to print outside the imageable area, but so far I haven't succeded, my last failure so far is:

```
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX()-50, pf.getImageableY()-50);
    g.drawString("Hello world!", 100, 100);
```

As always thanks for your time and help.

Comment: How does this fail exactly ?

Comment: Oh, well if I add lets say a g.drawString on a 10,10 location it doesn't print anything whatsoever. Altho the 100/100 moves slightly a bit to the left